# Using sweetalert with jquery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, sweetalert

I am doing some coding in Shopify, and I have gotten sweetalert to work in one instance but not in another. It seems like there should be an easy solution, but I can't find it.

I've created required fields for my cart ("cart attributes" in Shopify), so customers can't check out until they've completed these fields. I copied and pasted some script from Shopify to validate the required fields:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("body").on("click", '[name="checkout"], [name="goto_pp"], [name="goto_gc"]', function() {
        var e = !0,
            r = "Please fill in the required field (in red).";
        return jQuery('[name^="attributes"], [name="note"]').filter('.required, [required]').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("error"), e && "" == jQuery(this).val() && (e = !1, r = jQuery(this).attr("data-error") || r, jQuery(this).addClass("error"))
        }), e ? void
        jQuery(this).submit() : (alert(r), !1)
    })
}),
jQuery(window).unload(function() {
    var e = jQuery('form[action="/cart"]');
    if (e.size()) {
        var r = {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cart/update.js",
            data: e.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            async: !1
        };
        jQuery.ajax(r)
    }
});
```

This works fine and gives me the stock alert. But I'd like to show a sweetalert instead, mainly because the stock alert gives users the option to "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs," which I don't want.

After inserting the reference to the script source ("sweetalert.min.js") ahead of the script, I tried substituting "sweetalert" for "alert" like this:

```
  jQuery(this).submit():(sweetalert("Oops!",r),!1)})}),
```

But, perhaps not surprisingly, it doesn't work. Any ideas for a Javascript and jQuery newbie? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try it with jQuery(this).submit():(swal("Oops!",r),!1)})}), and let me know what kind of error you are having in console . also verify that the sweetalert.min.js is well linked

Comment: I have you tried `sweetAlert` with a capital A? The main site shows this in their example. http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/ or as @PacMan shows you and what I like to use is `swal`. It's faster anyways :)

Comment: The capital A was the answer--crazy that after all my tests and tweaks, it was something so simple! Presumably swal would work as well. Thanks for the help, all!